# What can cause Audio to fail one way in a WebRTC connection?

Tags: sockets, coldfusion, webrtc, voip

I have a chat and calling webapp on a server running coldfusion with a websocket. Normally, when I establish a webRTC connection between 2 peers, things go flawlessly. One peer creates an offer, which is sent to the receiving peer, who accepts and negotiates ICE servers. Connection is established and both peers can hear each other.
When I try to establish with certain peers, the connection is made, but only one side can hear the other's audio. This occurs every time a connection is made to this peer.

The webRTC connection gets to a connected status, so there are no issues there.

I have tried changing the way the webRTC offer is sent via:

- sending offers and negotiations through the websocket
- saving and reading them in an sql database on the same server
- saving and reading them in a Firebase Cloud Firestore DB
  I also verified that the peer's browser settings (chrome) were not impacting the audio. Access to the mic and speakers were granted to the site and the same mic was being used as Microsoft Teams was using.
  None of these efforts resulted in the peer being able to receive the audio and hear it.

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers? Different computers? It could just be an issue with that person's computer.

Comment: I tried this. The connection worked and audio was delivered both ways! I can't figure out why it wouldn't work with his chrome and how to prevent it in the future

Comment: Did you try different profile in Chrome? Also look into firewall/security software.. I run into similar issue and believe it or not, it was being caused by a Chrome Extension.